# Getting object required error when opening userform with button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the error`run-time error 424 object required` when I try to load my userform using the following code on a sheet module.  Code works fine in other workbooks.  Everything looks like it's spelled correctly.  Any clues what is going wrong?

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your CommandButton1 located?

Comment: It's on Sheet2.

Comment: Is your UserForm1 in your same Workbook?

Comment: yes it is.  It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Procedure in your Workbook Class to call your user form:

```
Public Sub OpenForm() 
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Then you can call your Sub from your button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call OpenForm
End Sub
```

Object events Subs are not `Public`

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference.  And that code works in other workbooks whether it is private or public.

Comment: VBA code is not supposed to call Object Events from other modules. But I'm not sure if you tried my suggestion or you are trying to get fixed your code by magic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to VBA.  I thought you could use a commandbutton_click sub in a worksheet module to open a UserForm.  Or are you supposed to put the sub in the UserForm module?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this time you first try the code before complain about it.